# Web App Security with Laravel and Android

Tags: php, android, laravel, kotlin

My team has a **Web App(Laravel)** and **Android Application written in Kotlin**. Our website has a Registration and Login forms but my problem is everyone can build their own app and call a POST method in registration form.

How can I **secure** our WebApp so that the only **POST METHODS** it accepts are just the forms from our own Android App and Web App?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't.

For web apps, you could restrict origin by allowing specific domains in your CORS config. But since mobile Apps can change their IP there is no 100% secure way to restrict a public endpoint (at least I didn't find it when I faced the same issue).

Anyway, you can try to add an extra security layer by including a request header with some encrypted content that must be decrypted and approved by your API.
But this is not completely secure, Android apps can be decompiled with reverse engineering and they will find how your encrypted header is done.

If Android apps are not public (can't be downloaded from Google play services) you can also try to use the installation_id generated, but it will change when the app is reinstalled. In this way, you can approve or reject requests as per installation ids

Comment: So how are the mobile apps accessing data in their server Privately?

Comment: Private endpoints require authenticated users. The most common scenario is using JWT token which is sent within every request. If the token is valid, the request proceeds, otherwise an auth error is returned

Answer (score 0):

You can JWT Tokens to verify the request .
If request is from a legitimate user then return the JSON data otherwise return an error . You can read more about JWT Tokens here
https://jwt.io/introduction

Comment: The issue here is about POST requests in registration/login forms, which are public endpoints hence the user has no token